# Can I not get Facebook notifications on Likes from people I don't know?

Tags: notifications, facebook

I manage a few FB Pages, and get tons of notifications. Specifically, whenever anyone likes a post on any of these pages, I get a notification.

Is it possible to unsubscribe from this specific set of notifications - whenever people I don't know like a post/page? I still want to receive all comment notifications, and Like notifications from my friends are interesting to me

Comment: Give us a screenshot. You cannot do anything about it if it is a sponsored story.

Comment: @user221287 - what? I'm not talking about my screen, I'm talking about the little red notifications that every user sees when people comment/like stories that he posted.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Facebook-Pages/Can-I-not-get-Facebook-notifications-on-Likes-from-people-I-dont-know